# Insert total number of slides in PowerPoint 2007

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2007

Is it possible to insert the total amount of slides in a PowerPoint presentation into a footnote? I'm looking for an automated way.

Of course I could edit the footer and put it in manually, but if I increase/decrease slides, it would be necessary to adjust it. And this is something that we always forget.

The [help from Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint/HA102425451033.aspx) explains how to do it manually. I can't believe that PowerPoint doesn't have it...

Comment: Is the "insert > field" option not available in powerpoint? That's how I used to do it in word...

Comment: Yeah, thats what I was looking for. I'm new to 2007 and I can't find it.

Comment: yea, fields dont exist in Powerpoint, so that won't work.

Comment: How irritating is it that we still need an add-in to this very basic feature? I've had this issue for years...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for an option or configuration setting that will just automatically add it to every presentation you create, there isn't one.  However, if you edit the Header or Footer, you can automatically add slide numbers there and have them appear on all slides.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint/HA101181931033.aspx

Comment: Yes, this is the article that I read. I don't want to have to put "of 10" manually. I'm looking for something like <#> of <##>...

Comment: Ahh, ok, yea, this would only work if you just want the page number.  If you want "of total slides" there isn't a quick solution.  The only other solution I can think of is to use VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) to accomplish this.  I know that will work, but could get a bit complex.

Comment: @BBlake You're right. VBA is required to achieve this. See [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/892103/156554) for details on how to do this.

Answer (score 7):

This is basically [*pwrpntuser*'s code](https://superuser.com/a/363398/156554) extended to full executable guide.

#### Creating macro

1. In PowerPoint 2007 and newer make sure, that you saved your presentation under `.pptm` extension (standard presentation with macros allowed).
2. Make sure, that you have added slide numbers using method described [in this article](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Add-a-slide-numbers-page-numbers-or-the-date-and-time-8a90ab4b-8e4d-4023-9a46-12f3313f356c?ui=en-US&rs=en-NZ&ad=NZ)<sup>1</sup>.
3. Open "*Macro*" window <sup>2</sup>. In PowerPoint 2007 and newer, click on `View` tab (last) and then on `Macro` button in last toolbar group. In eariler versions select `Tools > Macro` from menu.
4. Type a name for your macro (say `PageCountUpdater`) and click `Create`.
5. Paste macro code (from [*pwrpntuser*'s answer](https://superuser.com/a/363398/156554) or below) between `Sub PageCountUpdater()` and `End Sub`. Change `van` in the most indented line to `of` or anything similar in your lang.
6. Save macro and close Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications.Go back to PowerPoint.

You're done. Code to be inserted (full and with corrected "glue-word"):

```
Sub PageCountUpdater()
    Dim s As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape

    For Each s In ActivePresentation.Slides
        s.DisplayMasterShapes = True
        s.HeadersFooters.SlideNumber.Visible = msoTrue

        For Each shp In s.Shapes
            If Left(shp.Name, 12) = "Slide Number" Then
                shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = s.SlideNumber & " of " & ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
            End If

        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

#### Executing macro

1. Open "*Macro*" window again.
2. Select saved `PageCountUpdater` macro and hit `Run`.

You have to do this each time manually. A keyboard shortcut would be most welcome. But... there is no way to change PowerPoint's shortcuts, except for buying a commercial plugin, for which you have to pay price starting at 20 bucks per one computer. See end of [this](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-keyboard-shortcuts-to-create-your-presentation-ebb3d20e-dcd4-444f-a38e-bb5c5ed180f4) or [this](http://www.free-power-point-templates.com/articles/set-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-for-powerpoint-with-powerpoint-shortcut-tools/) article for a details.

#### Deleting macro

This macro is run only, when you need it. It is not a live-macro. It updates field with actual slide count and that's it. Field itself is a standard text field. No magic. This means, that you can easily convert your file back to `.pptx` and throw this macro away, once you're sure, that your presentation is done and you'll be adding no more slides to it. Field will remain in their places with their values untouched, once macro is removed.

This is comfortable as many users does not like documents with macros and many presentation places, fairs, conferences etc. simply won't let you run `.pptm` file.

This is also good, because this macro recreates numbering fields on all slides (except title ones -- see footnote no 1 at the end), even if you remove them manually. Therefore you should run it one last time, after you're sure about final number and order of slides and then you can remove it.

#### Opening macro-enabled file

If you decide to keep `.pptm` extension and macro inside, you'll have this document always opened with macros disabled and you'll have to click `Enable macros` each time (if you run on default settings) to enable them.

If documents are your own, you trust, that they contain no malicious code and they're all stored in a secure location (i.e. not in some temporal or shared folder), you can change each Office program settings to have these files always opened with macros enabled.

The easiest way is to add folder with macro-enabled presentations to secure locations in PowerPoint.

To do this:

1. Click `File` tab, `Options` button, `Trust Center` section and `Trust Center Settings` button.
2. Go to `Trusted locations` section (second) and click on `Add new location...` button.
3. Paste or select folder path into `Path` field and optionally check, that all subfolders in added location should also be treated as trusted.
4. Click `OK` three times to confirm and close all opened windows. Reopen your macro-enabled document.

From this point on, all documents opened from just added location should not display any warning and should always be opened with macros enabled. You'll find much more details on this matter in [this Office.com support document](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Trusted-documents-cf872bd8-47ec-4c02-baa5-1fdba1a11b53?ui=en-US&rs=en-IN&ad=IN).

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> <sub>In most versions of PowerPoint the meaning *title slide* is determined not as *first slide in presentation*, but as *any slide styled as title slide*. You can see diffreent slide types, when inserting new one. This mean that, if you have no slide styled as title, you'll have page numbers added to all slides. And opposite -- if you used many *title slides* inside presentation, for example to mark different sections or blocks, you'll have numbering missing on all of them.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>All GUI elements' names are on-the-fly translation from my Polish edition of PowerPoint 2010. In other releases or language editions of PowerPoint they may be slightly different. Adjust accordingly.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

First make sure every slide has a normal slidenumber. Then add a module, insert the following piece of code and press F5 (Start).

```
Dim s As Slide
Dim shp As Shape

For Each s In ActivePresentation.Slides
    s.DisplayMasterShapes = True
    s.HeadersFooters.SlideNumber.Visible = msoTrue

    For Each shp In s.Shapes
        If Left(shp.Name, 12) = "Slide Number" Then
            shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = s.SlideNumber & " van " & ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        End If

    Next
Next
```

Comment: What is a module?

Comment: When you programmatically change the contents of the slide number placeholder this way, slide numbers will no longer update automatically when you delete/add/move slides.  I would think this creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: This answer has been extended by [trejder in this other same question](https://superuser.com/a/892103/1007423), to explain to non-developers how to code it and save it.

Answer (score 3):

[Bill Dilworth's add-in](http://billdilworth.mvps.org/PageXXofYY.htm) for PowerPoint may help you, depending on which version of PowerPoint you're using.  This is exactly its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I found one web page that said you put <#> of x into a text box in the Master Slide and then add "slide number" to the slide.  I got it to work briefly, but then when I moved it, and tried again, it no longer populated the full slide number into x.  But this solution may be feasable for most users.

Comment: Yes... and this webpage is already mentioned here, in [an answer older 1,5 year than yours](http://superuser.com/a/130545/156554).

Answer (score 0):

Here's some slightly different code that updates your footer with "slide # of ##." I chose to not count hidden slides towards the total. I have this code executing from the mouse over of a hidden action button on slide 1.

```
Dim SlideTotal As Integer
Dim VisibleSlides As Integer
Dim SlideNum As Integer
Dim i As Integer

With ActivePresentation

    SlideTotal = .Slides.Count

    For i = 1 To SlideTotal
        If .Slides(i).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoFalse Then
            VisibleSlides = 1 + VisibleSlides
        End If
    Next

    For i = 1 To SlideTotal
        If .Slides(i).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoFalse Then
            SlideNum = 1 + SlideNum
            .Slides(i).HeadersFooters.Footer.Visible = msoCTrue
            .Slides(i).HeadersFooters.Footer.Text = "Slide " & SlideNum & " of " & VisibleSlides
        Else
            .Slides(i).HeadersFooters.Footer.Visible = -msoFalse
        End If
    Next

End With
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please be advised you have answered a question that is many years old and has an accepted answer. Although there is nothing wrong with doing so, it is unlikely you will get a response.